# angular+TS+jasmine+ng-html2js = 'Failed to instantiate module templates'. How to instantiate templates? Where is it forms?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine, ng-html2js

Trying to unit test angular's 1 directive with template in separate file. Using jasmine and ng-html2js to stash html templates in $templateCache. On a project without SystemJS one can use:

```
beforeEach(module('MyStupidModule', 'templates'))
```

where templates - is in 'carma.conf.js'

```
    preprocessors: {
        'Content/templates/**/*.html' : ['ng-html2js']
    },

    ngHtml2JsPreprocessor:{
        moduleName: 'templates'
    },
```

and it works just fine.

But with SystemJS we now must instantiate both those modules in order to make them reachable. It is simple to mock my own module,

```
...
        mockAngularModule('MyStupidModule');
        // angular.mock.module('MyStupidModule');
        angular.mock.module('store', 'templates');
..
```

but where can I put instantiation of this 'template' module? Now it throws

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module templates due
>   to:   Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'templates' is not available!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have the exact same issue. Thanks.

Comment: Nope. But since we use gulp to transpile and bundle everything, I just added a task where I gather all relevant html code and make a js variable of it in a separate js file. Then put this task as a dependency for karma task and tun tests. Not much of elegancy and simplicity, but it works.